# How do I put a height limit within a canvas game?

Tags: javascript, html

Right so I'm a bit new to JS and I wanted to know how to put a roof or height limit within this small canvas game. It's practically W3's code but the teacher told us to just model after it. I wanted to fix the annoying issue of just jumping over the map to avoid obstacles.

I don't really know what to try since the height is set by canvas. I tried to make a new function based of hitBottom() which failed.

Just wanted to put the roof or height limit. Here's the original source: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_default_gravity). Everything is literally the same except colors.

Comment: Create a similar method to `hitBottom` where you check if your y coordinate has hit a limit. If that happens reset the gravitySpeed back to 0 to prevent further rising.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is see if the current y-position is lower than 0, since that would be the 'roof' of the room. If the player y position is lower than 0, reset it back to 0, and stop the acceleration.

```
    this.hitTop = function() {
        if (this.y < 0) {
            this.y = 0;
            this.gravitySpeed = 0;
        }
    }
```

And to the newpos function, you want to call this function, so add this:

`this.hitTop();`

Answer (score 0):

Check for y position in `newPos` method after increasing the y position. If it is less than `0` then make it `0`. Code should look like below;

```
this.newPos = function() {
    this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;

    /* Add below 4 lines */
    if (this.y <= 0) {
        this.y = 0;
        this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    }
    /* Add above 4 lines */

    this.hitBottom();
}
```

Happy coding ;)